# Where do we register a custom DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am following this older answer I found to a problem I had:
[Set default for DisplayFormatAttribute.ConvertEmptyStringToNull to false across site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459560/set-default-for-displayformatattribute-convertemptystringtonull-to-false-across)

But I am pretty new to MVC, so when he says `Then register it in your app_start:`

Well App_Start is a folder with some classes in it, I have `BundleConfig, FilterConfig, RouteConfing and Startup.Auth` So in which of these classes should I register it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, open your Global.asax file. In there you will find an Application_Start method.  It may look something like this (you actual code will vary)

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
```

The Application_Start method is calling into each of the classes you see in the App_start folder.  Originally, we would include all of this code in the Global.asax, but it got pretty full, so a pattern developed to create single purpose classes in App_start and call them.

The line that you need to add could be directly beneath all the other calls like this

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new CustomModelMetadataProvider(); 
    }
```

If you find that the Application_start method is getting cluttered, you may replicate the pattern by creating a static class in the app_start folder and calling calling a static method to do the actual work.

Answer (score 1):

`Global.asax` file in the root of your project contains `Application_Start` method