# Set default for DisplayFormatAttribute.ConvertEmptyStringToNull to false in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, model-binding

I want to make `[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]` the default behaviour for my fields in an ASP.NET Core web application.

Related questions are for .NET Framework, and I am unsure on how to proceed with .NET Core

Related:

- [Set default for DisplayFormatAttribute.ConvertEmptyStringToNull to false across site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459560/set-default-for-displayformatattribute-convertemptystringtonull-to-false-across)
- [Set default for DisplayFormatAttribute.ConvertEmptyStringToNull to false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20308201/set-default-for-displayformatattribute-convertemptystringtonull-to-false)
- http://puredotnetcoder.blogspot.com/2013/09/convertemptystringtonull-in-mvc.html

I tried the following based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47345236/11141271), but it **doesn't work** and also breaks the attribute when I tried to include it anyways

```cs
public class EmptyStringAllowedModelMetadataProvider : DefaultModelMetadataProvider
{
    public EmptyStringAllowedModelMetadataProvider(ICompositeMetadataDetailsProvider detailsProvider) : base(detailsProvider)
    {
    }

    public EmptyStringAllowedModelMetadataProvider(ICompositeMetadataDetailsProvider detailsProvider, IOptions<MvcOptions> optionsAccessor) : base(detailsProvider, optionsAccessor)
    {
    }

    public override ModelMetadata GetMetadataForType(Type modelType)
    {
        if (modelType != typeof(string)) return base.GetMetadataForType(modelType);
        var identity = ModelMetadataIdentity.ForType(modelType);
        var details = CreateTypeDetails(identity);
        var context = new DisplayMetadataProviderContext(identity, details.ModelAttributes);
        DetailsProvider.CreateDisplayMetadata(context);
        details.DisplayMetadata = context.DisplayMetadata;
        details.DisplayMetadata.ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false;
        return CreateModelMetadata(details);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the following way, it works fine:

CustomMetadataProvider:

```
public class CustomMetadataProvider : IMetadataDetailsProvider, IDisplayMetadataProvider
    {
        public void CreateDisplayMetadata(DisplayMetadataProviderContext context)
        {
            if (context.Key.MetadataKind == ModelMetadataKind.Property)
            {
                context.DisplayMetadata.ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false;
            }
        }
}
```

registration service：

```
services.AddMvc()
             .AddMvcOptions(options => options.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(new CustomMetadataProvider()));
```

Test Result:
[image]

Comment: Excuse me, did my answer help you?

Comment: Will validate on Tuesday, blocked by some other tasks right now. Thanks for the response!